# VBA starts with or ends with a special character

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to see if a string starts with or ends with a special character

```
testString("#Testing")     Returns: true
testString("Testing\")     Returns: true
testString("#Testing)")    Returns: true
testString("Tes#ting~")    Returns: true
testString("Tes#ting")     Returns: false
testString("Testing")      Returns: false
```

The idea is to use a regular expression

```
Dim rg As Variant
Set rg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

rg.Pattern = ""

returnFunc = rg.test(paramString)
```

However, I am not sure how to create a regular expression to check symbols.

All alternative solutions are welcome

So if it starts or ends with anything other than [a-Z][0-9]

Comment: You will need to define exacly what you mean by "symbol".  Anything which is not a digit or character?  What about punctuation?

Comment: Are we considering English or are we considering other languages?

Comment: Anything that is not alpha numeric so anything but [a-Z][0-9]

Comment: English is that only language

Comment: `(^[^A-Za-z0-9].*|.*[^A-Za-z0-9]$)` is a regex that does that. Mind you: spaces and newlines are also special charcters.

Comment: Or `^([^A-Za-z0-9].*|.*[^A-Za-z0-9])$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function test(x)
    Dim rg As Variant
    Set rg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    rg.Pattern = "^([^A-Za-z0-9].*|.*[^A-Za-z0-9])$"

    test = rg.test(x)
End Function

Sub hoi()
    Debug.Print test("#Testing")
    Debug.Print test("Testing\")
    Debug.Print test("#Testing)")
    Debug.Print test("Tes#ting~")
    Debug.Print test("Tes#ting")
    Debug.Print test("Testing")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t need to change your definition of special characters for different languages or other reasons then you can simply checking the first and last character against a list of valid characters would work.

```
Public Function testString(text As String)        
    testString = isCharAlphaNumeric(Left(text, 1)) Or isCharAlphaNumeric(Right(text, 1))    
End Function

Public Function isCharAlphaNumeric(char)
    Const valid As String = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    isCharAlphaNumeric = InStr(valid, char) = 0
End Function

Public Sub test()    
    Debug.Print testString("#Testing")   '  Returns: true
    Debug.Print testString("Testing\")   '  Returns: true
    Debug.Print testString("#Testing)")  '  Returns: true
    Debug.Print testString("Tes#ting~")  '  Returns: true
    Debug.Print testString("Tes#ting")   '  Returns: false
    Debug.Print testString("Testing")    '  Returns: false    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if string does not start and end with alphanumeric characters using the VB [`Like` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/like-operator):

```
If Not "#Testing" Like "[0-9A-Za-z]*[0-9A-Za-z]" Then MsgBox True
```

If the string might be less than 2 characters:

```
If string Like "[!0-9A-Za-z]*" Or string Like "*[!0-9A-Za-z]" Then MsgBox True
```